I use Android Image Cropper ArthurHub and migrate to CanHub, but I got problem after that. I don't really understand
Sorry I just started android and I watched the tutorial "Make a Text Scanner App - OCR App - Full Tutorial - Android Development" on Youtube. He uses a library from ArthurHub and currently the library cannot be used. In the end I switched to the CanHub library. But I get the error Cannot resolve method 'setGuidelines' in 'CropImage' with code as below:
button_capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                CropImage.setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).start(MainActivity.this);
            }
});

additionally, I am getting the error Cannot resolve method 'getUri' in 'ActivityResult' and Cannot resolve method 'ActivityResult' in 'CropImageView' in the code I wrote as below:
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE){
            ActivityResult result = CropImageView.ActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), resultUri);
                    getTextFromImage(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

is there anyone who can help me?
I've tried looking at the documentation at Github but still don't understand how to apply the code.

Hi @Cahyo , did you come alright ? n if you yes would you please assist on how to fully implement it
